# Using regular expressions to find words with @

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a word with regular expression, but i don't know how to use it.

I will receive a text and a word and i have to find it in the text with and without **@** or **#**, and return **true** if i find it or **false** if dont find.

But it can't be in another word like this: "thisword".

It just can be alone and preceded by # or @.

How can i do this in Java ?

Example:

"the @horse is white"

"the #horse is white"

"the horse is white"

"A shorse is white"

i have to find the word horse, #horse and @horse in this three phrases.

Comment: Can you give some examples, the question is unclear.

Comment: accept an answer, I think you've solved your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
text.matches("\\b[#@]?" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b");
```

Answer (score 1):

OK...

1) Yes, there's a way.
[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html),
[and Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

2) I believe this will help you

```
public class TestRegex {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "cat";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[#@]?" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b");

    Matcher m = p.matcher("find c@t me @cat #cat c#t cat thiscat");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear due to lack of examples, however I believe this is what you mean:

```
str.matches(".*(#|@)");
```

This matches a string which includes either a # or a @.